# Saving textField data to a property in an NSObject Class

Tags: ios

I am quite new to iOS development so please be nice :) I am developing an app at the moment. *A user will register by filling in a form which is just a bunch of TextFields.*

Once the user registers they will be redirected to their homePage where a `UIImageView` and a `UILabel` will display there data they used when registering.

Now my issue is how to ensure that this `UIImageView` and `UILabel` display the same data everytime that same user logs in. I tried this using `NSUserDefaults` but when the user logs in it would display the users data that i just registered with. Any suggestions would be great and also I am using parse for my data base.

Here is the code for when a user registers

```
    NSLog(@"Registering user");

    MBProgressHUD *hud = [MBProgressHUD showHUDAddedTo:self.view animated:YES];
    hud.labelText = @"Registering";

    PFObject *parent = [PFObject objectWithClassName:@"Parent"];
    UIImage *image = form.profilePhoto;
    NSData *imageData =  UIImageJPEGRepresentation(image, 0.6);
    PFFile *imageFile = [PFFile fileWithName:@"image.jpeg" data:imageData];

    parent[@"Name"] = form.name;
    parent[@"Email"] = form.email;
    parent[@"Password"] = form.password;
    parent[@"Location"] = form.location;
    parent[@"ImageFile"] = imageFile;

    [parent saveInBackground];

    [parent saveInBackgroundWithBlock:^(BOOL succeeded, NSError *error) {

        if (!error) {
            [hud hide:YES];
            currentUser = YES;



            //saveData to parentUser
            NSUserDefaults *prefs = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
            [prefs setObject:form.name forKey:@"Name"];


            //Send user to parent home page
            PHomeViewController *lvc=[self.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"Phome"];
            SlideNavigationController *navcontroller = [[SlideNavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:lvc];
            ParentMenu *leftMenu = (ParentMenu*)[self.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier: @"LeftMenuViewController"];

            [self.navigationController pushViewController:lvc animated:YES];

            navcontroller.leftMenu = leftMenu;

            //save data to nsuserdefualts
            NSUserDefaults *defaults = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
            UIImage *uploadPhoto = form.profilePhoto;
            [defaults setObject:form.name forKey:@"Name"];
            [defaults setObject:UIImageJPEGRepresentation(uploadPhoto, 0.6) forKey:@"ImageFile"];
            [defaults synchronize];
            NSLog(@"Data has been saved");
        }
        else {
            NSLog(@"There was an error in registration");
        }
    }];


}
```

}

And this is the code that runs when a user logs in

- (IBAction)login:(id)sender {

  ```
  MBProgressHUD *hud = [MBProgressHUD showHUDAddedTo:self.view animated:YES];
  hud.labelText = @"Loading...";

  PFQuery *query = [PFQuery queryWithClassName:@"Parent"];
  [query whereKey:@"Email" equalTo:_Email.text];
  [query whereKey:@"Password" equalTo:_Password.text];
  [query getFirstObjectInBackgroundWithBlock:^(PFObject *object, NSError *error) {
      if (object) {
          NSLog(@"User logged in successfully");


          //Send user to parent home page
          PHomeViewController *lvc=[self.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"Phome"];
          SlideNavigationController *navcontroller = [[SlideNavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:lvc];
          ParentMenu *leftMenu = (ParentMenu*)[self.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier: @"LeftMenuViewController"];

          [self.navigationController pushViewController:lvc animated:YES];
          navcontroller.leftMenu = leftMenu;



      } else {
          // LOGIN ERROR
          UIAlertView *ALERT = [[UIAlertView alloc]initWithTitle:@"Error" message:@"There was an error logging in please try again later." delegate:nil cancelButtonTitle:@"Ok" otherButtonTitles:nil, nil];
          [ALERT show];

          _Email.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@""];
          _Password.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@""];
          [MBProgressHUD hideHUDForView:self.view animated:YES];
      }
  }];
  ```

  }

Thanks!

Comment: what you mean by "parse for my data base"?

Comment: are you store this register data to your data base?

Comment: You must show your code, "when the user logs in it would display the users data that i just registered with". NSUserDefaults stores the last update which you have made

Comment: i just added code that runs when a user clicks register in registration.m file. Now what i am trying to achieve is that i can later make decions which data to pull from database depending on each registered user?

Comment: and i am using a database called Parse

Comment: It's not clear to me what the difference is between what you're seeing and what you want to see.